# angular2 smart table is not working

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

angular2 smart table is not showing the table. I have followed the link [git hub](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table)

app.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { Ng2SmartTableModule } from 'ng2-smart-table';
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, Ng2SmartTableModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

request.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ItableValues } from './tableValues.component';
import { RequestFilterPipe } from './request-filter.pipe';
import { TableService } from './table-service.component';
@Component({
    selector: 'mm-request',
    templateUrl: 'app/dataManagement/request.component.html',
 
})

export class RequestComponent  {
    pageTitle: string = 'Request';
    imageWidth: number = 50;
    imageMargin: number = 2;
   
    settings = {
        columns: {
            id: {
                title: 'ID'
            },
            name: {
                title: 'Full Name'
            },
            username: {
                title: 'User Name'
            },
            email: {
                title: 'Email'
            }
        }
    };
    data = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Leanne Graham",
            username: "Bret",
            email: "Sincere@april.biz"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Ervin Howell",
            username: "Antonette",
            email: "Shanna@melissa.tv"
        },

        // ... list of items

        {
            id: 11,
            name: "Nicholas DuBuque",
            username: "Nicholas.Stanton",
            email: "Rey.Padberg@rosamond.biz"
        }
    ];

}
```

request.component.html

```html
<div>
    <ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="data"></ng2-smart-table>
</div>
```

Whenever i run the application, it shows only the first Loading page. 
[image]
All help will be appreciated.

UPDATE:
I have removed **Ng2SmartTableModule** used in declarartion as well as in bootstrap. It is used for a testing. please see the console log and error main.js file.
[image]

Error loading http://localhost:53869/app/main.js

```js
"use strict";
var app_module_1 = require('./app.module');
var platform_browser_dynamic_1 = require('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic');
platform_browser_dynamic_1.platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(app_module_1.AppModule);
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

Answer (score 0):

open your console then read your error log first.

`bootstrap` array and `declarations` array should not include this one `Ng2SmartTableModule`

please read this first:

> `NgModule` is a decorator function that takes a single metadata object
>   whose properties describe the module. The most important properties
>   are:
>
> `declarations` - the view classes that belong to this module. Angular
>   has three kinds of view classes: `components`, `directives`, and `pipes`.
>
> `exports` - the subset of declarations that should be visible and usable
>   in the component templates of other modules.
>
> `imports` - other modules whose exported classes are needed by component
>   templates declared in this module.
>
> `providers` - creators of services that this module contributes to the
>   global collection of services; they become accessible in all parts of
>   the app.
>
> `bootstrap` - the main application view, called the root component, that
>   hosts all other app views. Only the root module should set this
>   bootstrap property.

https://angular.io/guide/architecture